# PassportJs session not working when wrapping athenticate function

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js, express-session

so i have this problem with passportJS local strategy
it can't persist logins when i wrap passport.athenticate inside a function

- when i try to login on the route /loginT then go to /whoami it works just fine
- but when i use /login it responds with user object , but when i hit /whoami it log undefined
  i think i made a mistake somewhere but i can't find what's wrong with it

thank you

here's passport config

```
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
const UserDB = require('../models/users')
const { UserStatus } = require('../middleWares')
const signIn = new LocalStrategy (
    function( username , password , callback) {
        UserDB.findOne(
            {$or : [{username:username},{email:username}]},
            async function(err,user){
                if (err) callback({
                    success:false,
                    code:403,
                    message:err,
                }, false) ; 
                if (!user) 
                 callback({
                    success:false,
                    code:403,
                    message:'Username not found',
                }, false)
                if (!(await user.verifyPassword(password)))
                  callback ({
                    success:false,
                    code:403,
                    message:'Username or Password is incorrect',
                },false)

                if(user.status === UserStatus.PENDING_EMAIL_ACTIVATION) {
                     callback({
                        success:false,
                        code:93,
                        message:'Please Activate your account first',
                    },false,)
                }
                callback(null,user)
            }
        )
    }
) 
passport.use('local-signin',signIn)
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
  });
   
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    UserDB.findById(id, function (err, user) {
      done(err, user);
    });
});
module.exports = passport;
```

userRoute file

```
router.post('/loginT',passport.authenticate('local-signin',{
    failureRedirect:'/Login',
    successRedirect:'/'
}))

router.get('/whoami',async (r,res) => {
    console.log(r.user)
    return res.send({user:r.user})
})

router.post('/login',async (r,s)=>{
    passport.authenticate('local-signin',{},function(err,_user,info){
        if(err) s.send(err)
        if(_user) s.send({
            success:true,
            code:200,
            data:{..._user._doc,
                password:null,
                _id:null
            }})
    })(r,s)
})
```

server.js

```
const passport = require('./passport');  
app.use(require('express').json())
    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(require('express-session')({
        secret: 'keyboard cat',
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false
    }));
    
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
```

Answer (score 0):

*** SOLVED ***
i forgot to use request.logIn(user, function)
so i had to make the login route as next

```
router.post('/login',async function (r,s){
    passport.authenticate('local-signin',{},function(err,_user,info){
        if(err) s.send(err)
        r.logIn(_user,function(error) {
            if(error) return s.send({
                success:false,
                code:403,
                message:error,
            })
            return s.send({
                success:true,
                code:200,
                data:{..._user._doc,
                    password:null,
                    _id:null
                }})
        })
    })(r,s)
})
```